# Adding related dimensions to a SSAS Cube

Tags: sql, powerbi, ssas, dimensions

Hello there and thank for taking your time to read this. This is a very trivial question, however, it is a bit challenging to me. I am trying to add a related dimension in an existing cube and have been unsuccessful so far. I have gone through a few tutorials, but nowhere this concept is covered. I am very new to SSAS, Data Warehousing and SQL server so please bear with my ignorance.

I have documented the steps taken, https://1drv.ms/b/s!AugVuOwqQy9XiFoE2BFR5omxFXAZ?e=Zytp3y

If any additional information, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Thank You - KK (filesincloud@outlook.com)

Comment: You might find it easier to add the new CustomerLocation field to your existing Customer dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, this completely makes sense. However, my intention was to learn how to modify an existing cube. I work for an organization where I may be required to perform similar task where there are multiple table and 100K + rows and hence I posted this very simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to define a Snowflake schema.

You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models-olap-logical-dimension-objects/dimensions-introduction)

> Information from multiple tables is required to define the dimension. Each dimension is based on attributes from columns in multiple tables linked to each other and ultimately to the fact table by primary key - foreign key relationships.

For the Dimension table to Dimension table relationship, you need to use the [Referenced Relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models-olap-logical-cube-objects/dimension-relationships)

In simple terms, you need a set a relationship type. The below shows the different relationship types:

[image]

If you have the [AdventureWorks sample](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks), you can see the following Reference relationship defined:

[image]
You can now look at your dimension reference relationship and change it.

Good luck !

Comment: Hi Subbu. Thank you for the explanation. I will try this out. Very much appreciated.